# mPDF pagination problem when using WriteHTML function

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a dinamically generated HTML content and want to generate a page-numbered PDF using mPDF. The problem is that when the content spans more than one page, the footer is only visible in the last page.

Example:

```
$mpdf->AliasNbPages('{PAGETOTAL}');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content); // $content is dynamic, it can be a series of paragraphs resulting in a 3 or 4, or more, pages long pdf.
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}/{PAGETOTAL}'); // this only prints a footer in the last page, displaying for example "3/3", but the previous pages do not have footer
```

I want the footer in every page, but i don't know in advance how many pages I will have or where the pagebreaks will be.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `setFooter` before `WriteHTML`

So, this way:

```
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}/{PAGETOTAL}');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
```